# Как добавить в тело хедера параметр с функции

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Как я могу добавить в тело хедера параметр, который мне передается в методе

```
@Headers("Authorization: Bearer $token")
@DELETE("v1/auth/logout")
suspend fun logOut( token: String): Response<Any>?
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте аннотацию параметра метода вместо самого метода.

```
@DELETE("v1/auth/logout")
suspend fun logOut(@Header("Authorization") bearerToken: String): Response<Any>?
```

Источник:
https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Header.html

Comment: либо можно через перехватчик как вариант

Comment: Да, перехватчик тоже вариант. В случае доступности токена только как параметра вызова метода, его можно оформить как кастомный заголовок, который в перехватчике преобразовывать уже в Authorization

Comment: ага, просто в одном запросе такое норм будет, но согласитесь что если запросов будет уже 5+ то проще это пробрасывать через перехватчик)